ActiveMQ Artemis over HTTP
Goal
I have a server, where all the traffic to any public IP goes through proxy. I have configured https_proxy and http_proxy.
I want to connect to ActiveMQ Artemis running in cloud with public IP.
Now, when I hit a curl command to ActiveMQ Management Console I get the response, which implies that I am able to reach to the server
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Hawtio</title>
  <base href='/activemq/'>
  <link id="favicon" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico?v=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lib-6a1e4ce9ea.css"/>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app-9653e9917c.css"/>

  <!-- branding -->
  <link id="branding" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />

  <script src="js/lib-e53c220218.js" defer></script>

  <script src="js/app-fafe513f4b.js" defer></script>
</head>


<body>
  <hawtio-login></hawtio-login>
</body>

</html>

If I do a telnet to the ActiveMQ Server, it times out.
telnet <ip> 61616

broker.xml
<acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;supportAdvisory=false;suppressInternalManagementObjects=false</acceptor>

What I tried?
I tried to configure Netty over HTTP Protocol, but still it times out
artemis producer --url "tcp://<ip>:61616?httpEnabled=true" --user "artemis" --password "artemis" --message-count 1

I get this error:
Exception in thread "main" javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:915)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:314)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:309)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.commands.messages.Producer.execute(Producer.java:142)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.internalExecute(Artemis.java:219)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:165)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:157)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.main(Artemis.java:64)
Caused by: ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:735)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:913)
    ... 11 more


Why are you attempting to use HTTP for messaging? Why not just use a standard messaging protocol like AMQP or STOMP or even an ActiveMQ-specific messaging protocol like Core or OpenWire?

Added the error in question. Regarding why I am attempting to use HTTP - I can curl the console, implies network through layer 7 is passing the firewall, but when I telnet, i see a timeout, implies layer 4 ain't working. Though there is no hard and fast rule to use HTTP only.

That indicates the problem is with the network infrastructure, no? What can the broker do about that?

Yes, agreed. For layer 4, it is to do with network infra. But as layer 7 is working I was thinking about HTTP.

And yes If there is no option from layer 7, I will anyways need to talk to infra team. I was just looking for easier option.

What happens if you go directly to the broker and not through the proxy?

HTTP is really not a good protocol for messaging since it was designed for a completely different use-case. If there's any chance you can avoid using it you should try. It's really meant for environments where you have absolutely no choice. In any case, I don't think the client or the broker can really do anything here since the issue appears to be in the network somewhere.

From ther server, which has this proxy, is unable to reach the AMQ server. I get the same error. If I try using any other machine, which no network restriction, Im easily able to reach the broker(Broker is publicly available on internet).

I see. Ok, in that case will get this is sorted from the network infra to enable layer 4 too.

HTTP is really not a good protocol for messaging since it was designed for a completely different use-case. If there's any chance you can avoid using it you should try. It's really meant for environments where you have absolutely no choice. In any case, I don't think the client or the broker can really do anything here since the issue appears to be in the network somewhere.
